# How do I access the separate Internet Options for IE64 and IE32?

Tags: 64-bit, internet-explorer

How do I explicitly open the separate Internet Options for the 64bit and 32bit versions of Internet Explorer, without running Internet Explorer itself? A customer's 32 bit version of IE is crashing on launch, likely due to a bad plugin; but when I open Internet Options from the Control Panel, I appear to be getting the options for the 64 bit version of IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the command `"C:\Program Files(x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -extoff` to run it in safe mode. (or wherever the .exe is located on the machine). If it is an addon or an extension that is causing the problem then IE should start.

Depending on the version you have you can go to `tools >> manage add-ons` to examine your plugins.

For 64 bit you would access it by using the command

`"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -extoff`

If you know what plugin is bad you can find the install location and/or registry entry by right clicking the plugin under the manage add ons screen and choosing `more information`.

You could then try and remove it manually.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. I still think there must be a way to open a particular 'Internet Options' dialog, but this workaround was quite sufficient for to help the customer.

Comment: Not a problem. If you do find a way to do it with the Internet Options Dialog please share your answer.